# View arguments for File Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I installed a program that added some shortcuts to File Explorer when I have multiple files of a certain type selected. How can I find out what command line arguments are being passed to this program? I would like to be able to run it from the command line / write some scripts to automate some tasks.

The program is WinRAR, and when I have multiple .rar or .zip files selected and right click I see the following: "Extract each archive to a separate folder"

Answer (score 0):

If only a few file names are involved then you can use a setup like this. Create a batch file with the following content in any convenient folder.

```
echo "Parameter 0: "%0
echo "Parameter 1: "%1
echo "Parameter 2: "%2
echo "Parameter 3: "%3
echo "Parameter 4: "%4
echo "Parameter 5: "%5
echo "Parameter 6: "%6
echo "Parameter 7: "%7
pause
```

I will call it **seeThem.bat**. Make a shortcut to it in the same folder (right-click & create shortcut). For the sake of neatness, discard the ' - Shortcut' part of the name.

Launch Windows Explorer and in the address line key **shell:sendto**. Cut-and-paste the shortcut you've just made into the SendTo folder.

Now go to a folder where you want to see what happens when you select multiple files and use the context menu. You should see **seeThem.bat** as one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

While the program to find the arguments for is running, open a PowerShell Window and type:

```
(GWmi win32_process -Filter "name = 'winrar.exe'").commandline
```

You may have to confirm that `WinRAR.exe` is actually the process name for the WinRAR application.

The output should be the full path to the executable plus any parameters passed to it.

You can also use Task Manager. Open the `Details` tab, right click on any column header and choose `Select columns`. In the list of columns, check `Command line`.